# Why is ActionMailer failing? SMTP To address is required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, sendgrid

I'm racking my brain trying to figure out what the heck is going on here...

I call `BidMailer.confirm(Bid.last.id).deliver` in the rails console and I'm getting the following error:

*ArgumentError: An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.*

My code:

**environment.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  user_name: ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  password: ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  domain: ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN'],
  address: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  port: 587,
  authentication: :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

**environments/development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

**mailers/bid_mailer.rb**

```
class BidMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def confirm(bid_id)
    @bid = present Bid.find(bid_id)
    mail(
      to: @bid.user.email,
      subject: "Your request for #{@bid.event_name}"
    )
  end
end
```

If I print out `@bid.user.email`, my email shows up properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `from` address e.g. `mail(to: "example@example.com", subject: "Your request for #{@bid.event_name}", reply_to: "example@example.com)`. Also try replacing `@bid.user.email` with a string to debug.

Comment: The from is defined in `ApplicationMailer`

Comment: Additionally I already specified that `@bid.user.email` has been confirmed to be a valid email address

Comment: As a first debug I would hardcode all values like `ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME']` and `@bid.user.email` as your environment might not be able to access all variables